# How to make summary for input type number in row and column

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make summary of input type number for row and form comlun. And I don't know how to do it in jQuery. Important to me is the fact the summary of input in row and will work dynamic. Anynowe have any idea how to make this work?

```
<table style="width: 100%;" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="number" /></td>
<td><input type="number" /></td>
<td>summary row</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="number" /></td>
<td><input type="number" /></td>
<td>summary row</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>summary column</td>
<td>summary column</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: To answer your question - Yes I have an idea how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, this sums the first column. The jsfiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/tLX85/

```
$("input").keyup(function() {

    var rowSum = 0;

    $("tr td:first-child input").each(function() {
        rowSum += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });

    $("#sumcol1").html(rowSum);

});
```